# Simple way to change current URL

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a simpler way to change 2 variables on the current url without having to split the url and re-building it.

for example if i have a url `http://www.anysite.com/any/12/this/url/10/20` and want to change the last to variables `10` and `20` to `20` and `30` for example is there are simpler way than using `window.location.href.split("/")` then having to re-build the whole url?

Comment: rebuilding is going to be the only way, though there are alternatives to `split()`.

Comment: I think you can use regex match function to do the task u desire? not sure though

Answer (score 2):

With the regexp function replace:

```
url.replace(/([0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)$/, function( str , n1 , n2 ){
  var new_n1 = 10 + parseInt( n1 , 10 );
  var new_n2 = 10 + parseInt( n2 , 10 );
  return new_n1 + '/' + new_n2;
});
```

this replaces a part of the string which have the format: [number]/[number] and which is at the end of the string 'url' (because there's a $ at the end of the pattern) by a string which have the format: [number+10]/[number+10].

Comment: +1 for providing a dynamic solution. You should close your replace call with a close parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression would be the best way to avoid spilting, if that's what you want.

See (for instance):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

As for replacing the URL, it would be a matter of `location.replace(/* new URL here*/)`, with the benefit of actually replacing the URL in the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab it is a string then trim and append as you see fit.

You could grab it as a string and use search and replace.

You could grab it as a string and run GREP against it.

But, honestly, might be easiest to just do the split/array thing.

It all depends on the formatting rules you have to adhere to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
var url = "http://www.anysite.com/any/12/this/url/10/20";
var newURL = url.replace(/10\/20$/, "20/30");
```

This regex looks for "10/20" at the end of the URL and replaces it with "20/30".  Depending upon what exact circumstances you want to do the replacement, you might tweak the regex a bit to allow or disallow certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a function you can use.

```
function amendHref( a, b) {

    var str = window.location.href;

    var newHref = str.replace( /[\d]+\/[\d]+$/, a + "/" + b );
    //                          ^^^^^          digit one or more times
    //                               ^^        ( escaped ) forward slash
    //                                  ^^^^   digit one or more times
    //                                      ^  end of string

    window.location.href = newHref;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TcSa5/)